# how to dynamically give a value to a radio button in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, radio-button

I'm making an app using jQuery and javascript, this app depends on using a radio buttons that is getting it's values from an XML file, so i can't predict the value before running the code as it depenfs on the processing of the code, and here's the piece of code i'm taking about:

```
oc=$('menu').find($(".selected").text()).children().eq(si).children().length
optionstring=''
for(oi=0;oi<=oc-1;oi++)
{
itemoptions[oi]=$('menu').find($(".selected").text()).children().eq(si).children().eq(oi).prop('nodeName'); // that's the value i wanna asssign
optionstring=optionstring+'<input type="radio" name="iCheck" id="icheck" ><p style="line-height:10px; font-size:15px;">'+(itemoptions[oi]).toString()+'</p>' here i wrote the value as a paragraph and that make it not related to the radio button
}
}
```

i tried making it like that :

```
optionstring=optionstring+'<input type="radio" name="iCheck" id="icheck" value=(itemoptions[oi]).toString()>
```

but that gives me **"(itemoptions[oi]).toString()"** not the value of it.

Comment: Use AngularJS. There is very simple data binding.
This is very bad practice 
'itemoptions[oi]=$('menu').find($(".selected").text()).children().eq(si).children().eq(oi).prop('nodeName');'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are better alternatives, but you would have to refactor some other code too. The quick way would be:

`optionstring += '<input type="radio" name="iCheck" id="icheck" value="' + itemoptions[oi] + '">';`

*Note that you do not have to call `toString()` since anything concaneted with a string is converted to a string automatically.*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`optionstring=optionstring+'<input type="radio" name="iCheck" id="icheck" value=('+itemoptions[oi]).toString()+'>';`

There's a mess with quotes

Answer (score 0):

Try this one with jQuery example,

```
$("#icheck").val(itemoptions[oi]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply have a problem with your string.
Why are you not using $.each :

```
$('menu .selected').children().eq(si).children().each(function(i, ele) ({
  optionstring += '<input type="radio" name="iCheck" id="icheck" value=' + ele.val(); + '">';
});
```